# Find out CPU model given a user-mode crash dump

Tags: windows, windbg, system-information

I have a crash dump for my app. My app fails for some user saying “invalid instruction” trying to execute some SSSE instruction I have there.

In WinDBG, how do I find out the CPU model, so I can find out its instruction set, and either support the instruction set, or update minimum hardware requirements of the app?

Here’s the output of `!cpuid`:

```
CP  F/M/S  Manufacturer     MHz
 0 16,4,3  <unavailable>   3000
 1 16,4,3  <unavailable>   3000
 2 16,4,3  <unavailable>   3000
 3 16,4,3  <unavailable>   3000
```

The rest of the commands google says might help (!errrec, !cpuinfo, !sysinfo) print “No export found”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely aren't getting much information here. Although dumps don't usually have *all* of the raw CPU information, you should at least be seeing a manufacturer string. Oh well, let's look at what you do have to work with here...

The `CP` column gives the logical processor number, so you know you're dealing with a system that has 4 logical processors. Could be a quad-core, or perhaps a dual-core with HyperThreading.

`F/M/S` is Family/Model/Stepping, which are a common and fairly standard way to identify processors. As AMD says:

> The processor *Family* identifies one or more processors as belonging to a group that possesses some common definition for software or hardware purposes. The *Model* specifies one instance of a processor family. The
>   *Stepping* identifies a particular version of a specific model. Therefore, Family, Model and Stepping, when taken together, form a unique identification or signature for a processor.

It is most helpful if you have the manufacturer when you go looking for these things because the family numbers are pretty messy, but thankfully it's pretty clear that a family number of 16 (10 in hexadecimal) corresponds to an AMD processor (which should have a manufacturer string of "AuthenticAMD"). Specifically, it is the [AMD K10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_10h), which is the Barcelona microarchitecture. That means there's no HyperThreading—this is just a native quad-core system.

We can narrow it down further by looking at the model. There were lots of different models based around the Barcelona core, branded variously as Athlon II, Opteron, Phenom, Phenom II, Sempron, Turion, and V-Series. Yours is model 4. This is where it gets kind of tricky, because I don't know of a good resource that lists the model numbers and steppings for various CPUs. You have to go directly to the manufacturer and wade through their manuals. For example, [here is AMD's Revision Guide for the 10h Family](http://support.amd.com/TechDocs/41322_10h_Rev_Gd.pdf). If you go to the "Processor Identification" section (appears as a bookmark in the PDF for me), you see something that looks promising, but the information is certainly not presented in an easily-digestible form. You get long hexadecimal values, out of which you have to extract individual bits corresponding to the Family (8-11), Model (4-7), and Stepping (0-3).

I didn't do all the grunt work to be certain, I'm just making a quick guess that this is an AMD Phenom II X4. The X4 fits with the quad-core, and from a cursory glance, it appears that the Phenom IIs are model 4.

Anyway, you could have probably stopped a while back, because the microarchitecture tells you everything you need to know. This is an AMD Barcelona core, which doesn't support [Supplemental SSE3 (SSSE3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSSE3) instructions (*three* S's—not to be confused with SSE3; the naming conventions are ridiculous). SSSE3 was invented by Intel, released with the Core 2 microarchitecture.

AMD didn't implement them until Bobcat/Bulldozer. [Bulldozer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulldozer_(microarchitecture)) was the subsequent generation, family 21 (15h), for desktops and servers, while [Bobcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobcat_(microarchitecture)) was the low-pore cores for AMD's APUs.

SSSE3 didn't really offer that many new instructions. Only 16, primarily intended for working with packed integers, and most of them [aren't very exciting](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/SSSE3). The dump *should* also tell you the opcode of the instruction that caused the crash. If not, you'll have to go back and figure it out from the code's byte address. This will tell you exactly which instruction is the problem. I'm guessing that you are using [PSHUFB](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PSHUFB.html) to shuffle bytes in-place, which is the one SSSE3 instruction that is actually pretty useful. One common use I've seen is [a fast population count algorithm](http://wm.ite.pl/articles/sse-popcount.html) (although there are other implementations that don't require SSSE3 that are almost equally as fast, if not faster).

Assuming that you're compiling with MSVC, I'm actually sort of surprised to see it emitting this instruction. In order to get it, you'd have to tell the compiler to target AVX, which would stop your code from running on anything older than Sandy Bridge/Bulldozer. I'm sure if you don't want to bump up your minimum system requirements, you can figure out an alternative sequence of instructions to do the same thing. `pshufd`, or `movaps` + `shufps` are possible candidates for workarounds.

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Yes, building with visual studio.

It’s not the compiler emitting those instructions. I’ve vectorized my code manually using intrinsics. AFAIR it became about two times faster compared to automatic vectorization to AVX2: my algorithms mostly process integer numbers / bit masks, gigabytes of them, and I’ve coded a lot of bit tricks processing those __m128i values. I don’t believe automatic vectorization is capable of doing optimizations comparable to what I did here.

Comment: As you see, the CPU compatibility is the downside of that approach: I was really disappointed when I’ve realized for the last decade there’s no longer such thing as x86 instruction set, Intel/AMD has diverged. Looks like I can only rely on SSE 4.1 and below, and they’re 9 years old already…

Comment: Just when I think I'm catching up there's a post like this that amplifies how far I still have to go. You could have gone right to the grunt but choose to make it educational and that's an understatement. Write a book. I'll buy it.

Comment: @soonts Automatic vectorization still has a long way to go. It is very easy to beat at this point by some smart manual vectorization. Having more instructions available (i.e., targeting later instruction sets) certainly can help, but it isn't essential to wring out speed. Optimizers still leave a lot of low-hanging fruit, or just make bad decisions. There haven't been 30+ years of improvements to the optimizer on this front like there have been for basic integer ops. Especially if the code is complicated, as you say.

Comment: @soonts But to be fair, there never really was such a thing as *the* x86 instruction set. Even since MMX (Intel-only) and 3DNow (AMD-only), there have been very different instruction sets available on different manufacturers' processors and different families. Agreed there are several big problems now, though, like Intel stealing all the opcode space for itself, and vendors both rushing to release new competing instruction set "standards" instead of working together. I'm sure if you asked about the relevant bits of code here, you could get an alternate implementation for an older architecture.

Comment: @CodyGray You guessed correct: discovered I did count bits using that PSHUFB instruction.
But I didn’t gave up, instead implemented runtime features detection, so my code will use SSSE or XOP or SSE2 whichever’s available. Did theoretically lost something ‘coz no longer inline, but profiler says I’m OK with that, probably because __vectorcall.

Comment: @Soonts Sounds like a plan. You know, you could do the feature detection once, say at application startup, and cache away a pointer to the correct version of the function. That call should be correctly predicted each time thereafter, making it essentially free on repeated calls. This is precisely what Intel's compiler does for its own math library functions. Not sure if that would help you here. Gotta trust your profiler! But I am a big fan of continuing to support hardware for as long as reasonably possible, even if things run slower or there are fewer features on those machines.

Answer (score 4):

The commands `!sysinfo`, `!cpuinfo` and `!errec` are kernel dump commands, defined in the *kdexts* extension, so they are not available in user mode debugging and probably won't work well if you load that extension explicitly.

The only idea to get more information from the dump I had was `.dumpdebug` which will output a Stream called `SystemInfoStream` that looks like this:

```
Stream 7: type SystemInfoStream (7), size 00000038, RVA 000000BC
  ProcessorArchitecture   0000 (PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL)
  ProcessorLevel          0006
  ProcessorRevision       2A07
  NumberOfProcessors      04
  ... (OS specifics) ...
```

Unfortunately, that's exactly the same as displayed by `!cpuid`, so there's really no more information contained in the dump.